# Rank of block triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, block-matrices

suppose that $C$ is full column rank matrix,
can we say that the following equality is true:

$$\operatorname{rank}\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\B & C
\end{bmatrix}\biggr)= \operatorname{rank}\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
A \\B 
\end{bmatrix}\biggr) +\operatorname{rank}(C)$$

I have an idea about it:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\B & C
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\B & 0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\0 & C
\end{bmatrix}$$.

Now using the inequality, $\text{rank}(A+B)\leq \text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)$ results in

$$\operatorname{rank}\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0\\B & C
\end{bmatrix}\biggr)\leq \operatorname{rank}\biggl(\begin{bmatrix}
A \\B 
\end{bmatrix}\biggr) +\operatorname{rank}(C).$$

The equality holds whenever ${R}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
A \\B 
\end{bmatrix}\right) \cap R(C)=0$ and  $C\left(\begin{bmatrix}
A \\B 
\end{bmatrix}\right) \cap C(C)=0$.

But how to conclude it in this case?!

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1866974/rank-of-a-lower-triangular-block-matrix)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot say the equality is true. For example,

$$\mathrm{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\right)\neq\mathrm{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)+\mathrm{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

Comment: Yes, You are right. But under what conditions we can say that?!

Comment: It should be true since I see this in many papers and books! but without any proof and refer! it seems that it should be trivial!!

Comment: and how about if $A$ is invertible?

Comment: @imhs please refer us to an example of a paper or book saying such a thing. "should be true" says nothing if you are given a counter example.

Comment: @GuySa please look at this for example: robust model-based fault diagnosis for dynamic systems by Chen and Ron Patton on page 75.